# Nearly-uniformally sampling lattice points from a basis that lie on the interior of a polytope

Tags: co.combinatorics, lattice, integer-lattice

**Definitions:**

Consider a polytope $P \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with a nonempty interior to be $P : \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n | Ax \le B\}$ for appropriate real $n \times m$ matrix $A$ and $m \times 1$ vector $B$.

Furthermore consider a lattice $L$ to be all points spanned by positive integer linear combinations of a basis set of vectors $\mathbb{B} = V_1, V_2, ..., V_b$ where $V_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$, so that $L = \{\sum_{i}{c_i \times V_i} | c_i \in \mathbb{Z}^+\}$.

**Referenced work:**

[Random points and lattice points in convex bodies](http://www.renyi.hu/~barany/cikkek/rsurv.pdf) I Bárány et al

[Sampling Lattice Points](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.71.1583&rep=rep1&type=ps) R Kannan et al

**Problem:**

The above referenced work illustrates how one might randomly sample integer lattice points within the body of a polytope and use the results to approximate the size of the polytope, which is known to be $\#P$ hard to calculate in the general case. Furthermore they give sufficient conditions for when the sampling procedure will output a reasonable approximation (within polynomial factors).

These two papers assume the input lattice is the integer lattice $\mathbb{Z}^n$. For my application, I want lattice points spanned by a separate basis set.

**Question:**

While the general procedures used in the above papers to sample random integer lattice points seems adaptable to other lattices, the bounds necessary for nearly-uniform sampling may not. Do the same bounds and sampling procedures hold immediately for other basis vectors?

More directly, I am seeking a quick (polynomial time) nearly-uniformal sampling procedure that can output points in $P \cap L$ with inputs $A, B, n, $ and $\mathbb{B}$.

Comment: Why can't you apply an affine transformation to space that takes the lattice to the integer lattice ${\mathbb{Z}^n}$ and the convex polytope to a different convex polytope?

Comment: Not all lattices can be mapped to $\mathbb{Z}^n$. For example, if the lattice is spanned by the basis $\{<0,1>, <1,0>\}$ there is no transform between the two if $n > 2$.

Comment: All full-dimensional lattices can be mapped to ${\mathbb{Z}}^n$. If the lattice isn't full-dimensional, you can take the intersection of the polytope with the subspace spanned by the lattice, and obtain a smaller-dimensional problem.